# How to run `OpenFin Process Manager`

Tags: node.js, openfin

Refer to https://github.com/openfin/process-manager

Based on the README.md, I have done the following steps:

1. npm install
2. node server

I am able to see the following message from terminal(windows 7)

```
$ node server
Express server listening on port 5040
```

How do I launch the application?
I have tried to point to the `localhost:5040` through chrome browser and ONLY see three tabs '**Processes**', '**Cache**', '**Logs**' without any information.

How can I fix the issues?

Comment: Did you download and run the "Local Process Manager Installer"?

Comment: I download all source code ZIP file and cannot run *.exe file on my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm i -g openfin-cli
openfin -l -c http://localhost:5040/app_local.json
```

The server script is running a local express server that hosts an OpenFin enriched web app so all you need to do it launch it on OpenFin, which in the case above we are doing with the CLI.

You can also use a node module to launch i.e. [here](https://github.com/dcchuck/process-manager/tree/feature/local-launcher)